# Find Facebook Friends using the same Parse app

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I need to find users that I'm Facebook Friends with that are using my app (I have an Android and Web version). I was able to get this done on Android with this code:

https://parse.com/questions/how-can-i-find-parse-users-that-are-facebook-friends-with-the-current-user

But there's no mention of a method for Javascript.

I've seen from other posts to do a FB api call something like this:

```
            FB.api('/me/friends?fields=installed', function(response) {
                var friends = response;


                console.log(friends);
            });
        }
```

But for some reason that is only returning 7 of my friends (this is the case even when I'm just searching /me/friends). I'm not sure why it's not returning my entire friendslist.

Answer (score 4):

You don´t need the `fields=installed` parameter, `/me/friends` will already return friends who authorized your App too. Since v2.0 it does not return all friends anymore, you can read more about that in the [changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog).